# LiveData two-way databinding WITHOUT exposing MutableLiveData

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I'm trying to use two-way databinding on a EditText, that works fine if I expose the field as MutableLiveData as it is usually seen on examples I found online.

However there are good reasons not to expose MutableLiveData and those reasons aren't magically invalid because I decided to use the databinding library.

### EDIT: The main motivation here is MyViewModel should remain in control of setting data (this is the reason why it is not recommended to expose `MutableLiveData` directly), in the setter I can perform whatever checks or transformations necessary and then just call `setValue` on the LiveData.

I usually expose a `LiveData` getter and a separate setter from my ViewModel, I tried to get this working with two-way data binding by using the `InverseMethod()` annotation, but that won't really work because databinding is looking for a InverseMethod to `getValue()` of the LiveData itself.

Here is a simple example:

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<String> mEmail = new MutableLiveData<>();

    // @InverseMethod("setEmail")    ### THIS DOESN'T WORK
    public LiveData<String> getEmail() {
        return mEmail;
    }

    // ### I WANT DATA-BINDING TO USE THIS METHOD
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        if (mEmail.getValue() != email) {
            mEmail.setValue(email);
        }
    }
}
```

and this how a want to bind it

```
<EditText
   android:id="@+id/input_email"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@={viewmodel.email}"/>
```

the only workaround so far that works is using one-way data-binding to set the text on the EditText and then attach a TextWatcher and call my ViewModel.setter from there.

EDIT:
second workaround is to extend MutableLiveData and then do the checks and transformations in an overridden `setValue` ... that's a lot of boilerplate to write.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. This is exactly how I would like to do it but I don't know. The workarounds are too much overhead so I'm going for exposing the MutabeLiveData when I do TwoWay Databinding. Would be nice if there's a better solution.
The error message says: `There is no inverse for method getValue, you must add an @InverseMethod annotation to the method to indicate which method should be used when using it in two-way binding expressions`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've forgotten about this issue for a while, but as a workaround I've extended `MutableLiveData` slightly and use this instead every time I need control over the setter.

```
import androidx.core.util.Consumer;
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;

public class DelegatedMutableLiveData<T> extends MutableLiveData<T> {
    private Delegate<T> mDelegate;

    public interface Delegate<T> {
        void onSet(T value, Consumer<T> setter);
    }

    public DelegatedMutableLiveData(Delegate<T> delegate) {
        mDelegate = delegate;
    }

    public DelegatedMutableLiveData(T value, Delegate<T> delegate) {
        super(value);
        mDelegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(T value) {
        if (mDelegate != null) {
            mDelegate.onSet(value, super::setValue);
        } else {
            super.setValue(value);
        }
    }
}
```

now use `DelegatedMutableLiveData` as follows:

```
private final DelegatedMutableLiveData<Integer> mMyLiveData = new DelegatedMutableLiveData<>((value, setter) -> {
    // do your checks and change value if necessary
    setter.accept(value); // or don't accept if you don't want to change the current value
});
```

Answer (score 9):

We have been recommended to switch from ObservableField to LiveData for data binding because it is lifecycle-aware. We have also been recommended not expose MutableLiveData because the view model should control assignment.

This works perfectly for one-way data binding and in those cases I would only expose LiveData.

We want to use two-way data binding, which by definition moves assignment from the view model to the UI, so I think in this case exposing MutableLiveData is correct. I say this as we are doing it on purpose because we want our UI to be able to assign values so that we have cleaner views.

Comment: The issue remains the same, you lose control of the setter. Just as an example, your UI has an EditText and you want to limit what kind of text should be acceptable. Now you'll need another TextWatcher just to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same question, that´s how i found yours.
I know it´s not exactly what you are looking for but an option would be to observe mEmail from your ViewModel, and implement your setEmail() code in it (after the value itself has been set of course... i don´t know how to control setting the value which is what you are looking for i guess)

```
val observer = Observer<String> { setEmail(it)}
fun setEmail(value:String){ //Your code }
init{
    mEmail.observeForever(observer)
}
//Don´t forget to remove the observer
```

Comment: Thanks Gio for the feedback, the issue with this method is, that all other observers will at least temporarily see the invalid value.